# Forma correcta de usar un Web Service en servidor local desde Xamarin

Tags: c#, json, webservice, xamarin

Tengo una pequeña app en Xamarin que debe hacer una consulta a un web service alojado en un servidor local y mostrar el resulrado en un listview, la cuestión es que no logro que me muestre nada en el listview al correrla en android. No sé si estoy cometiendo algún error al acceder al servicio web desde la app.

Adjunto el codigo donde usa el web service

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace RestPrueba
{

    // Learn more about making custom code visible in the Xamarin.Forms previewer
    // by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //BindingContext = new modelo.Posts();
            LlenarInventario();
        }
        private async void LlenarInventario()
        {
            HttpClient Cliente = new HttpClient();

            string url = "https://192.168.0.10:80/Wsprueba.php?prod_pos=000450";
            var resultado = await Cliente.GetAsync(url);
            var json = resultado.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            Consulta modelo = Consulta.FromJson(json);
            Inventarios.ItemsSource = modelo.Producto;
        }
    }
```

Al correr la app me da el siguiente error 
Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 'Handshake failed'

Comment: eres capaz de acceder a ese servicio desde un navegador normal a ese servidor, `https://192.168.0.10:80/Wsprueba.php?prod_pos=000450` pero en el mismo pc donde tengas Xamarin funcionando? O es exactamente el mismo PC? si es el mismo PC, has probado con la dirección local `127.0.0.1` en vez de la 192?

Comment: Proba hacer debug y fijate si resultado tiene informacion o esta null;

Comment: Disculpa, en donde puedo ver si el resultado tiene información o es null? no lo encuentro.